# Align missing data in siunitx S column type

Tags: tables, siunitx

How can I align missing data inside a S column type like in the below image?

[image]

If I just add `{\textemdash}`, the dash is not centered, example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{lS} 
Case & {Variable} \\ 
First & {\textemdash} \\
Second & 15 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please add the code for your table?

Comment: How should we know without seeing your code? The `{...}` does not work in general for all cases.

Comment: Sorry, added a MWE.

Comment: That em dash *is* centered AFAICS. The `15` is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably your are misunderstanding where the centre of the column is. Usually, it's best to tell `siunitx` how many digits to allow for, for example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc
  S[table-format = -1.6]
  S[table-format =  1.6] % Or perhaps -1.6, see text!
  S[table-format = -1.6]
  S[table-format = 2.4]
  S[table-format = 1.4]
}
\toprule
Atom num & Atom type & {$x$} & {$y$} & {$z$} & {NMR tensor} & {NMR Shift} \\
\midrule
46 & H & -1.433234 & 2.735618 & -2.223064 & 29.7894 & 2.0656 \\
46 & H & -2.833329 & 1.693382 & -1.950341 & 29.0105 & 2.8445 \\
47 & H & -2.559918 & 3.103363 & -0.892348 & 30.514  & 1.341   \\
48 & N &  2.23005  & 0.694822 & -1.070475 & {\textemdash} & {\textemdash} \\
49 & H &  1.515066 & 0.996756 & -1.729488 & 30.5467 & 1.3083 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that without setting `table-format`, `siunitx` has to assume that the number can be any size. It therefore uses a strategy which centres the decimal marker, which depending on the numbers then used may look unsymmetrical but does produce the documented outcome (aligned `.`).

Note that you might want to use the same format for all three columns for *x*/*y*/*z* co-ordinates, or you might want to 'squeeze' up the *y* column as there are no signs here: an aesthetic decision!

Comment: That works, thank you. If I don't provide the format, how does `thesiunitx` calculate the center?